# ReactJS <input type="date" > format date

Tags: reactjs

I have to format the date to `DD-MMM-YYYY` format. I Am using reactjs. The date is formatted in `IE` but `not in Google Chrome`. Please suggest.

```
<input  name="requested_order_ship_date"  type="date" 
        disabled={ this.state.mode } 
        value={ moment(this.state.item.requested_order_ship_date).format("DD-MMM-YYYY") } 
        className="form-control"  onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

Comment: <input  name="requested_order_ship_date"  type="date" disabled={ this.state.mode } value={ moment(this.state.item.requested_order_ship_date).format("DD-MMM-YYYY") } className="form-control"  onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with React. For `<input type="date" />` values, browsers expect the `value` of the date to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

See [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) for more info.