# How to change the date format in ReactJS hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I need to change the format type of date from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`, if not possible what other options i have? I don't think using jQuery in a React Project is a good choice.

```
<input type='date' />
```

The default value of this is `mm/dd/yyyy`. This is stopping my work flow, as i can't skip it since the client insist to have the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS <input type="date" > format date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397107/reactjs-input-type-date-format-date)

Comment: The value of an input type date is always yyyy-mm-dd. The format displayed in the UI is dependent (mostly) on the browser language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to change the format for `input type='date'`. This actually has nothing to do with React. It is the browser which sets the proper format according to the locale of your browser.

you can use custom react component to force this.

Just a quick search from google: [React Date Picker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Comment: The displayed format tends to be based on *navigator.language*, but not always. There is no navigator locale. ;-)