# Changing the details of input type date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask if they is any way to edit my input type date so it shows only `dd-mm-rrrr`, I'm making Book managment system which connects with Postgresql API and if I make an input like this:

```
 <Form.Group controlId="releaseDate">
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="date" name="release_date" defaultValue={props.release_date} placeholder="Write the release date of the book" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>
```

the result is something like this: `2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z`

Is there any way to change it or is a problem of API, the database that converts it to something like this?

`handleInputChange`

```
 const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value

        setBook((prev) => ({...prev, [name]: value}));
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919671/how-to-remove-time-value-in-datetime-local-input-type

Comment: as you can see, I use type="date", so the solution shown in the link you sent is not good for my case.

Comment: well then something is wrong, since: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397107/reactjs-input-type-date-format-date/46175697

Comment: if everything was good, I wouldn't have written there :P

Comment: what's in `handleInputChange`?

Comment: I edited my post, where I added `handleInputChange`

Comment: if you `console.log(value)` right after `const value = e.target.value`, what's the output?

Comment: it prints line by line each value I put into input. As for date, it's good: e.g. 2021-05-09

Comment: that means the value is manipulated later on. you should inspect `setBook()` to see if value is changed there